# É errado retornar nulo em uma Task?

Tags: c#, .net, cache, .net-core, task

Tenho a seguinte implementação de `MemoryCache`:

```
public Task<News[]> GetCandidateNewsAsync(string candidate)
{
    return _cache.GetOrCreateAsync(candidate, async factory =>// _cache é um IMemoryCache
    {
        var candidateUri = _candidateUris[candidate];

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(candidateUri))
            return null; //retorno nulo aqui (erro)

        var candidateNews = await _candidateNewsClient.GetCandidateNewsAsync(1, candidateUri);

        return candidateNews?.News;
    });
}
```

Rodei um analisador de código em cima do meu projeto e ele reportou o seguinte:

> Do not return null from this method, instead return 'Task.FromResult(null)', 'Task.CompletedTask' or 'Task.Delay(0)'

Só que eu não entendi direito, qual o problema de retornar nulo nessa ocasião? Qual o sentido retornar um delay de 0ms como ele recomenda?

Comment: Você poderia colocar o cabeçalho do método?

Comment: Feito @Maniero ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa é uma resposta [retirada do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45347160/is-it-better-to-return-an-empty-task-or-null-c-sharp):

*Não é certo retornar uma `Task` nula. Uma `Task` nula é como se ela nunca tivesse sido chamada, mas ela foi.*

*Então, uma `Task`/`Task<T>` retornado de um método nunca dever ser `null`. Mas ainda assim você pode retornar o valor nulo dentro da `Task`.*

---

#### Qual o problema de retornar nulo nessa ocasião?

No meu caso, provavelmente foi um falso alarme do meu analisador, já que eu não estava retornando a `Task` como nula, e sim o valor nulo dentro da `Task`, o que é totalmente correto.

Explicando melhor, o método [`GetOrCreateAsync`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.caching.memory.cacheextensions.getorcreateasync?view=aspnetcore-2.1) do `IMemoryCache` recebe como parâmetro um tipo genérico(`<T>`), e uma `Func<ICacheEntry, out Task<T>>`, e como a minha task era assíncrona, quando eu retornava nulo, ele não estava retornando a `Task` como nula, e sim o valor dentro da `Task`, do tipo `News[]` como nulo.

---

#### Qual o sentido retornar um delay de 0ms como ele recomenda?

Um `Task.Delay` de 0ms é a mesma coisa de retornar um `Task.CompletedTask`, veja como é implementado no [código oficial](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/Task.cs) do [.net-core](/questions/tagged/.net-core): *(linha 5407 no momento que estou escrevendo)*

```
public static Task Delay(int millisecondsDelay, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    // ...
    if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        // return a Task created as already-Canceled
        return Task.FromCanceled(cancellationToken);
    }
    else if (millisecondsDelay == 0)
    {
        // return a Task created as already-RanToCompletion
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do ponto de vista semântico não faz sentido uma Task retornar null.
No mundo de execução assíncrona, você retornar null é 'como se você tivesse falando' pro código que uma tarefa não foi executada ou não existe, porém, no seu caso, ela existe.

O erro está te dizendo pra você fazer com que a `Task` retorne um valor `null` (`TaskFromReult(null)`) ou então que retorne que a tarefa foi executada (`Task.CompletedTask`).

Isso tudo pois é assim que se usa as tasks normalmente, faz parte das boas práticas.
Quando você executa uma tarefa assíncrona, você espera que ela retorne se foi executada ou não, você não espera ela ser `null`.
Pense que esse tipo de análise é para as outras pessoas que possam vir utilizar seu código futuramente.

Comment: Você pode colocar como o código dele ficaria?

Comment: Basta trocar `return null`  por `return Task.FromResult(null)`  .

Comment: Adicionado o exemplo @Maniero

Comment: @Francisco isso é porque o método precisa retornar um vetor do tipo `News[]`, não tinha essa informação anteriormente tinha?
Sendo assim você precisa retornar algo do mesmo tipo. Pode tentar algo do tipo: Crie um vetor do tipo `News` com valor `null` e retorne-o.
`News[] nw = null`  retorne  `return Task.FromResul(nw)`.

Isto deve funcionar.

Sobre o `Task.Delay(0)` : segundo a referência da MS, ele executa a `Task.CompletedTask` quando o tempo é igual a 0ms. Pode ver mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18527223/1469170)

Comment: Cara, fiz um pequeno programinha de teste aqui e funcionou.. 
Segue o [link](http://rextester.com/ILCGC20068)